# String of values separated by commas being split unevenly on carriage return

Tags: reporting-services

I have a field that contains a list of serial numbers separated by commas, e.g. "0001,0002,0003,0004".  When I display that value in a textbox, it looks fine unless the amount of serial numbers requires a carriage return.  In this case, the serial numbers get "split up", because the textbox doesn't know that they should be split by the commas if it is the end of a line.

I am not sure how to tell SSRS to insert a carriage return only after a comma.

[Serial Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDRO2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try replacing the commas with comma-space. The word wrap should then handle this correctly.

if you are getting the data from SQL Server then you would do something simple like

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(myColumn, ',', ', ') AS myColumn, 
    myOtherColumn, 
    myYetAnotherColumn
FROM myTable
```